# ¿Qué son los thread o qué es un thread?

Tags: hilos

Soy nuevo en esto de los threads y leyendo en varios sitios al respecto me di cuenta que no me era fácil entender el tema con las explicaciones re-contra técnicas de lo que sucede en el hardware. ¿Existe alguna analogía que me pueda ayudar a entender el concepto?

Comment: Me parece que este tipo de preguntas se deberían hacer en http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Hector No existe una versión en español de programmers.se. [Ya se debatió](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/161/23) que en este sitio no seríamos tan estrictos con la temática como en el sitio en inglés, y aceptaríamos este tipo de preguntas (con unos criterios mínimos de calidad, por supuesto).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A mí me gustó mucho cómo lo definían en [Processes and Threads](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.0/neutrino/getting_started/s1_procs.html). Se trata de visualizar los *threads* como habitantes de la casa, en la que el proceso principal es la casa en sí misma.

La analogía indica que si vives solo eres *single-threaded*: todos los recursos son tuyos, puedes usar el baño cuando quieras, la nevera siempre tendrá lo que dejaste en ella la última vez, encender la luz a medianoche no molestará a nadie, etc.

Por contra, en una casa con varios *threads*, es decir inquilinos, todo o bastante es compartido: la cerveza que dejaste en la nevera ayer puede que hoy se la haya bebido alguien, lo mismo alguien enciende la luz de tu habitación a media noche, etc. Pero, por supuesto, tienes las ventajas de compartir muchos recursos para facilitarse la vida.

Pero entonces, ¿por qué es bueno ser *multi-threaded*? Sin entrar en temas sociales para no apartarnos demasiado del mundo de la informática, el hecho de compartir recursos hace más óptima la vivienda: se reparten los gastos (luz, gas, electricidad tienen cuotas fijas y otras dependen del uso), se optimiza el uso de los espacios (casi cualquier habitación está deshabitada la mayor parte del tiempo), etc.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, quizás la pregunta `¿por qué es bueno ser multi-threaded?`, debería reescribirse a `¿En qué ocasiones beneficia "ser multi-threading"?` http://stackoverflow.com/a/10110693/3866134