# Utilizar el mismo Runnable en dos Threads diferentes

Tags: java

```
class RaceDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Racer racer = new Racer();
        Thread tortoiseThread = new Thread(racer, "Tortoise");
        Thread hareThread = new Thread(racer, "Hare");
        //Race to start. tell threads to start
        tortoiseThread.start();
        hareThread.start();

        try {
            hareThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Racer implements Runnable {

    public static String winner;

    public void race() {
        for (int distance = 1; distance <= 100; distance++) {
            System.out.println("Distance Covered by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "is:" + distance + "meters");
            //Check if race is complete if some one has already won
            boolean isRaceWon = this.isRaceWon(distance);
            if (isRaceWon) {
                break;//Si alguno ya ganó, el otro no sigue 
            }
        }
    }

    //              -       -
    //            -           -
    //          -               -
    //        -                   -
    //      Thread1               Thread2
    //      race 1                 race 2
    //

    private boolean isRaceWon(int totalDistanceCovered) {
        boolean isRaceWon = false;
        if ((Racer.winner == null) && (totalDistanceCovered == 100)) {
            String winnerName = Thread.currentThread().getName();//Devuelve el nombre del thread que está ejecutando el código en ese momento.
            Racer.winner = winnerName; //setting the winner name
            System.out.println("Winner is :" + Racer.winner);
            isRaceWon = true;
        } else if (Racer.winner == null) {
            isRaceWon = false;
        } else if (Racer.winner != null) {
            isRaceWon = true;
        }
        return isRaceWon;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.race();
    }
}
```

¿El método de `race()` es el mismo que se utiliza para cada thread?

Osea, el *thread1* llama al método y el *thread2* también por lo tanto, en consola no tendría que salir que ganaron los dos?

Uno antes que el otro, pero como llamaron al método dos veces, tendría que ganar uno y después el otro...

Pero en consola solo salta que ganó uno y luego corta el programa...

Comment: te sugiero este tutorial en español http://dhw.umh.es/alex-bia/teaching/PC/material/hilos_tutorial-java/cap10-2.htm , saludos!.

Comment: Ahora mismo lo reviso, graciass

Comment: Así a bote pronto, parece una demo sobre cómo implementar hilos usando como ejemplo el cuento de la liebre y la tortuga

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro parece, pero tiene muchos problemas. Es más, puede resultar que ambos ganen =S

Comment: Te sugiero que busques otro material para aprender sobre hilos. Este ejemplo tiene muchos problemas.

Comment: Estuve toda la tarde tratando de entenderlo y ni siquiera la lógica de los if del método isRaceWon() pude entender.

Comment: por cierto hay un race condition el código... le falta `synchronized` a `isRaceWon`..

Comment: igual puede que esto le ayude en rasgos generales http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1642/qu%C3%A9-son-los-thread-o-qu%C3%A9-es-un-thread Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La idea que intenta representar el código me parece que es la siguiente. La explicación del código va en comentarios

- Tener una clase `Racer` que traducido sería `Corredor`. Esta clase implementa la interfaz `Runnable`. Esta clase tiene un campo estático y dós métodos:

  - `static String winner` o ganador: Campo estático que almacenará el nombre del ganador de la carrera.
  - `void race` o carrera: Método que evalúa la distancia que ha recorrido este corredor en la carrera. Indica si es que el corredor debe seguir corriendo o no en base al resultado de `isRaceWon` o esGanadorDeLaCarrera.
  - `boolean isRaceWon(int totalDistanceCovered)` o esGanadorDeLaCarrera: Método que evalúa si el corredor es el ganador en base a la distancia.
  - `void run` o correr: Método que ejecutará el hilo al iniciarse. En este caso, indica que al iniciar el hilo, esta instancia de `Runnable` empezará a competir en la carrera.

  Entrando en más detalle por cada método de la clase `Racer`, encontramos lo siguiente:

  ```
  public void run() {
      //Solo ejecuta el método race. Cuando termine la ejecución
      //del método race, termina la ejecución del hilo
      this.race();
  }

  public void race() {
      //el ciclo for controla el avance del corredor
      //el avance se encuentra definido en la variable distance
      for (int distance = 1; distance <= 100; distance++) {
          //Impresión de mensaje de la distancia recorrida por el corredor
          System.out.println("Distance Covered by "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "is:"+distance +"meters");
          //Evaluar si algún corredor ha ganado la carrera
          boolean isRaceWon = this.isRaceWon(distance);
          //si alguien ya ganó la carrera, detener el ciclo for
          //y por ende, detener su participación en la carrera
          if (isRaceWon) {
              break;//Si alguno ya ganó, el otro no sigue 
          }
      }
  }

  private boolean isRaceWon(int totalDistanceCovered) {
      //variable que almacena el resultado de las operaciones realizadas
      //en el método
      //esto se utiliza para tener un solo punto de salida (un solo return)
      //se inicializa con el valor por defecto
      boolean isRaceWon =  false;
      //evalúa si el valor del campo estático winner es nulo
      //y si la distancia enviada como argumento es 100
      if ((Racer.winner == null) && (totalDistanceCovered == 100)) {
          //al parecer estas condiciones definen al ganador
          //por ende se asigna el valor del nombre del hilo
          //como el nombre del "ganador" (mal diseño)
          String winnerName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
          Racer.winner = winnerName;
          //imprimir el nombre del ganador
          System.out.println("Winner is :"+Racer.winner);
          //indicar que ya existe ganador en la carrera
          isRaceWon = true;
      } else
          //agrego este comentario y el indentado para explicar que 
          //efectivamente no se cumplió alguna de las condiciones anteriores
          //pero puede que ya exista un ganador o no de la carrera
          //así que se evalúa si Racer.winner ya está asignado
          if(Racer.winner == null) {
              isRaceWon = false;
          } else if(Racer.winner != null) {
              isRaceWon = true;
          }
      //devolver si alguien ganó la carrera
      return isRaceWon;
  }
  ```
- Tener una clase `RaceDemo` o `DemoDeCarrera` que demuestre cómo se comportan 2 corredores al competir entre ellos. El código del método `main` es conciso:

  ```
  //Crear una instancia de Racer
  Racer racer = new Racer();
  //Utilizar la misma instancia de Racer en dos hilos (mal diseño)
  //A cada hilo se le asigna un nombre más humano para entender mejor
  //el código
  Thread tortoiseThread = new Thread(racer, "Tortoise");
  Thread hareThread = new Thread(racer, "Hare");
  //Se inicia la ejecución de cada hilo
  tortoiseThread.start();
  hareThread.start();

  //El hilo principal de la aplicación espera a que el hilo
  //referenciado por la variable hareThread o hiloConejo
  //termine su ejecución
  try {
      //el método join puede lanzar la excepción InterruptedException
      //aunque en este escenario es poco probable que suceda
      //de igual forma se debe manejar la excepción que lanza
      //(diseño dudoso)
      hareThread.join();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

Comment: Graciiias ya entendí gran parte del código. Solo que sigo confundiéndome con que cada thread tiene su propio método race() y que es allí donde se dividen los corredores(porque tienen la misma instancia de race, solo que llaman al método y el método los divide).  No sé si logro explicar mi confusión

Comment: Una explicación decente para un código que de por sí es desastroso :/

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer es una carrera de Threads y no importa que halla un solo Racer pues el contador `distancia` es propio de cada thread al estar definido en la función `race`. En términos generales no hay ninguna razón para no usar el mismo `Runnable` en dos threads, pero debes tener cuidado en la implementación pues los miembros de la clase serán compartidos entre ambos threads. En la mayoría de los casos prácticos, utilizarías diferentes instancias.

#### Pero esto tiene un bug

El método is `isRaceWon`, así como esta, puede ser accesado por ambos hilos al mismo tiempo, por lo que existe una condición de carreta (o race condition <sup>[ref 1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condici%C3%B3n_de_carrera)</sup>).

Nunca sucederá que ambos ganen, pues hay una sola variable para guardar el ganador. Sin embargo es un error de implemetación y es una buena oportunidad para que lo aprendas pues esta situación es bastante común.

Java tiene una forma muy simple de solucionar esta *condicion de carrera* (cuantas carreras, parece un examen). Se llamada *synchronized methods*   <sup>[ref 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)</sup> y agregando el modificador `synchornized` a la declaración de la función, impide que ambos hilos accedan al metodo al mismo tiempo (pues hay un solo Runnable). Esta sentencia se resume en algo así: aquí solo entra un hilo a la vez.

Seria.. `private synchornized boolean isRaceWon(int totalDistanceCovered)`

Esto evita que tengas un falso ganador. O mejor dicho que el segundo, logre establecer su nombre como el ganador, a pesar de haber llegado segundo.

#### Sobre agregar dos racers.

Si quieres duplicar los racers, solo para probarlo, tienes que sincronizarlo de otro modo, pues el recurso a proteger es `Racer.winner` y al ser dos instancias, el mecanismo anterior no sirve. Pero Java tiene otro mecanismo para este tipo de problemas, llamado *synchronized statements* <sup>[ref 3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)</sup>.

Seria así:

```
private boolean isRaceWon(int totalDistanceCovered) {
    boolean isRaceWon =  false;
    // este es el bloque protegido que no pueden ingresar dos threads a la vez.
    synchronized(Racer.winner) {
        // desde aqui
        if((Racer.winner==null )&&(totalDistanceCovered==100)){
            String winnerName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            Racer.winner = winnerName;
            // hasta aqui, es la zona critica
            System.out.println("Winner is :"+Racer.winner);
            isRaceWon = true;
        }else if(Racer.winner==null){
            isRaceWon = false;
        }else if(Racer.winner!=null){
            isRaceWon = true;
        }
    } // fin del bloque protegido     
    return isRaceWon;
}
```

Luego puede instanciar dos racers y pasarle uno a cada thread, para ver que sucede!